# React-Select not working when options dont have label/values

Tags: reactjs, select, react-select

I am using react-select and it is not working for me. My options come from an API fetch and it does not have value and label property. Is there any way to use existing JSON Array.

```
const awards = [{"name":"Award A","ID":1},{"name":"Award B","ID":2}]

<Select value={awards.name} options={awards} />
```

Does the options array need to have label and value property? I dont want to restructure my JSON Array. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `getOptionLabel` and `getOptionValue` [props](https://react-select.com/props) to set the value and options.
For example:

```
<Select 
  getOptionLabel  = {(option)=>option.name}
  getOptionValue = {(option)=>option.id}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. one addition is that we need to add options={awards} attribute to the select.